# Decode incoming SMS numbers

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command

I use some SIMCOM GSM module to receive incoming messages. When I send SMS from my mobile phone I see my normal number:

```
+CMT: "+38012345678", ...
```

But when SMS comes from my cell operator, or some named SMS service as Google I see somу trash like here from Google:

```
+CMT: "16p6p6w237562767963656", ...
```

one more:

```
+CMT: "w49511#495946535451425", ...
```

and more:

```
+CMT: "#497966737471627", ...
```

According to module documentation this parameter named `<oa>` and means GSM 03.40 TP-Originating-Address Address-Value string field.
Is it possible to decode it on any programming language, e.g. from python? What can it be? If I switch to UCS2 and decode from it is absolutely the same.

Answer (score 2):

According to SIM800 Series AT Command Manual v1.10, page 114:

> GSM 03.40 TP-Destination-Address Address-Value field in string
>   format; BCD numbers (or GSM default alphabet characters) are converted
>   to characters of the currently selected TE character set (refer
>   Command +CSCS in 3GPP TS 27.007); type of address given by

If phone number in CMT message does not start with "+" sign, it is encoded with BCD numbers.

I tried to compare those numbers with ASCII table. This is not exactly BCD encoding, but looks very similar.

To decode "16p6p6w237562767963656" split it into pairs: `16 p6 p6 w2 37 56 27 67 96 36 56`

then reverse each pair: `61 6p 6p 2w 73 65 72 76 69 63 65`

Now compare to HEX codes in ASCII table and get the result: `all services`. You may wonder how to read `6p 6p 2w`. I wonder either!

After searching other examples of encoded numbers I made an assumption that HEX digits 0, A-F have equivalent of different characters:

```
0 - w
A
B - #
C - p
D
E - +
F - @
```

I have no idea, why HEX digits were replaces by random letters.

`"w49511#495946535451425"` stands for `"@Y?KYIVSTAR"`. The code `"11"` is unprintable and replaced by `"?"`.

`"#497966737471627"` stands for `"Kyivstar"`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your module is set to text format (AT+CMGF=1) when receiving those SMS? If you switched off your module and on again it probably is set to "PDU" mode, which is more suited for computers than humans..

See the SIMCOM AT Command manual for details, it's very extensive (380 pages pdf).

Comment: yes, I am sure, I configure it on boot, and also PDU mode have other AT command structure. Maybe it is vendor text mode issue